# HTML5 Input type "number" in Firefox

Tags: firefox, forms, html

I am working on an app that is only used by a few people in-house, so I feel comfortable telling them to only use Firefox or Chrome, so I can use HTML5.

I was working on a very simple feature:

```
<style> 
input:invalid { background-color: red; }
div.box {
border-color:#000; 
border-width:thin; 
border-style:solid;
}
</style>     
<input type="number" name="id"> <small>(if the box becomes red, make sure you didn't put a space)</small>
```

It works great in Chrome: it becomes red and won't let you submit, without me coding anything else.

Firefox ... not so much. It acts as if I had a "text" type.

Is that a known issue? Workaround?

Thanks

Comment: If it becomes red? http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-without-color.html

Comment: interesting article. However like I said, this is used by like 5 people who are in the same office as me. So if red is no good, I'll know pretty quickly.

Comment: Vote for https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=344616 ! It'll probably be done in the first release after FF4, so maybe mid-2011

Comment: @Adam: Version 17 now... still doesn't appear to be implemented.

Comment: @Mark Shows what I know... Here is the browser support table: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number

Comment: @Mark people over at mozilla are still meandering around without implementing this... The first issue was raised on [bugzilla in 2006](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=344616). 7 Years. NOTHING! Unbelievable.

Comment: Version 27, still nothing. Wow!

Comment: And version 29 finally implements number inputs. (Unfortunately, they're still somewhat ugly a year later.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, are you using Firefox 4? HTML5 forms has much better support in version 4.

This page has details on HTML5 forms and the current bugs
https://wiki.mozilla.org/User:Mounir.lamouri/HTML5_Forms

Update: If the browser does not support the HTML5 features you want to use, try [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/). It uses Javascript to enhance support. It's documentation has [information about input types](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#inputtypes).

Comment: I'd rather wait for the release version before I make them upgrade. :( I though 3.6 would be good enough ...

Comment: It won't matter. Firefox 4 beta doesn't have support for input number yet. It might have in the final version, though.

Comment: Firefox 12 (Linux) still doesn't have support for input number yet. bummer. Modernizr looks like the way to go.

Comment: I still don't see support for this type in the latest Firefox nightly (Firefox 17.0a1 (2012-08-01)). I doubt it will be coming anytime soon.

Comment: That's odd. Does anyone know why mozilla refuses to support it?

Comment: Nevermind. It turns out they are not happy with the current spec: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=344616 and it's currently "on pause", ie, not coming anytime soon. Bummer, because I kinda like the spinner controls on Chrome, but if it's not cross compatible I'll have to drop it.

Answer (score 6):

> Is that a known issue?

Yes. Unknown types are treated as text. (And types which only appear in draft specifications tend to be unknown by many browsers)

> Workaround?

[JavaScript](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#modernizr)

Answer (score 5):

`input type="number"` is not implemented in Firefox yet as of version 25 (November 2013).

Bug 344616 is the relevant ticket in Bugzilla@Mozilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=344616

**Update 10 March 2014** - Good news! Looks like the ticket was fixed in Firefox 29, [scheduled](https://wiki.mozilla.org/RapidRelease/Calendar) for release on 29 April 2014.

**Update 30 April 2014** - Confirmed, I just gave it a try, and Firefox 29 has support for `input type="number"`.

Answer (score 4):

**No** browser gets this yet. Mileage may vary, but there is definitely work to be done in all browsers.

Opera will show you an UI letting you click arrows up and down to increase or decrease the number.
You can however submit the form even if anything but a number has been entered. Accessibility is not perfect yet, but at least you can also use the arrows of the keyboard to increase and decrease the number.

Chrome has no UI for the number yet, thus there is no help or *no visual hint* that a number is expected. Chrome also has no real error message. Turning the input border slightly red is definitely not good enough as a default and it is **totally inaccessible**. Chrome basically is the worst offender of all browsers when it comes to accessibility, e.g. zero support for ARIA.

You are using the *:invalid pseudo-class* to make the entire input widget red. Please recognize that this may be clearer than the default styling in Chrome, but it is still not an accessible solution. Since Chrome does not support ARIA, the bad news is that even if you'd provide a text error message through JavaScript, a blind user, or anyone else using a screen reader, might not hear it at all.

Firefox may be late to this game, but please recognize the fact that Mozilla have [very strict shipping criteria for its features](https://wiki.mozilla.org/User%3aMounir.lamouri/HTML5_Forms#Shipping_Criteria), while Chrome plays around with no thought about consequences.

Answer (score 1):

i am using firefox, i had the same issue developing my input type number typing caracters and spaces etc...
anyway i m using angular 2 in this examples, its almost similar to javascript, so you can use this code in every case :
here is the html :

```
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="qte" type="number"  min="1" max="30" step="1" [(ngModel)]="numberVoucher"
     (keypress)="FilterInput($event)" />
```

here is the function FilterInput :

```
FilterInput(event: any) {
        let numberEntered = false;
        if ((event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57) || (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40)) { //input number entered or one of the 4 directtion up, down, left and right
            //console.log('input number entered :' + event.which + ' ' + event.keyCode + ' ' + event.charCode);
            numberEntered = true;
        }
        else {
            //input command entered of delete, backspace or one of the 4 directtion up, down, left and right
            if ((event.keyCode >= 37 && event.keyCode <= 40) || event.keyCode == 46 || event.which == 8) {
                //console.log('input command entered :' + event.which + ' ' + event.keyCode + ' ' + event.charCode);
            }
            else {
                //console.log('input not number entered :' + event.which + ' ' + event.keyCode + ' ' + event.charCode);
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
        // input is not impty
        if (this.validForm) {
            // a number was typed
            if (numberEntered) {
                let newNumber = parseInt(this.numberVoucher + '' + String.fromCharCode(event.which));
                console.log('new number : ' + newNumber);
                // checking the condition of max value
                if ((newNumber <= 30 && newNumber >= 1) || Number.isNaN(newNumber)) {
                    console.log('valid number : ' + newNumber);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('max value will not be valid');
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
            // command of delete or backspace was types
            if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.which == 8) {
                if (this.numberVoucher >= 1 && this.numberVoucher <= 9) {
                    console.log('min value will not be valid');
                    this.numberVoucher = 1;
                    //event.preventDefault();
                    this.validForm = true;
                }
            }
        }
        // input is empty
        else {
            console.log('this.validForm = true');
            this.validForm = false;
        }
    };
```

in this function i had to just let the keypress of numbers, direction, deletes enter, so this function is just for the positive integer not doubles.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has supported patterns since 4.0

```
 <input name="hours" type="number" pattern="[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+"/>
```

(For help, see http://html5pattern.com/)