# HTML5 input type date, color, range support in Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

I've build all my website using many forms with HTML5 (using the `input` types `date`, `color` and `range`.)

Everything works fine in Google Chrome.

But when I turn on Internet Explorer and Firefox, all input fields become like `input` type `text`.

Is there a way or a script I can download to make forcing the displaying of this input correctly?

Comment: what `doctype` are you using?

Comment: I use this doctype <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: I found a similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269004/html-5-input-type-number-in-firefox

Comment: The html5 doctyp shold be `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: color type is being supported by firefox now..

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Since HTML5 hasn't been completely standardized yet, not all browsers do support these input types. The *intended* behaviour is to fall back to `<input type="text">`.

↪ [See here for more information on browser support for HTML5 input types.](http://caniuse.com/#search=input%20type)

You can [test for support](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#input-types) using the Modernizr library or with some custom JavaScript. If you detect a certain HTML5 feature isn't available, you can fall back to [JavaScript](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)-[based](http://www.queness.com/post/10081/11-javascript-color-pickers-plugins) [alternatives](https://startpage.com/do/search?q=javascript%20slider%20input).

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've find a way in a french website. http://41mag.fr/tutoriel-html5-comment-faire-un-formulaire-complet.html the thing is that I met again some trouble. But this post Is ok. thanks for your help.

Comment: Here is working solution: http://www.zeeshanarshad.com/how-to-get-firefox-html-5-date-input-andor-ie-10/

Answer (score 6):

All browsers fallback to input type text if special input is missing. Its all about widgets and validation.

**Following support range widget**

Firefox Desktop 23

[image: Firefox 29]

Opera Desktop

[image: Opaera]

Chrome Desktop

[image: chrome desktop]

Chrome Mobile

[image: Chrome mobile]

IOS safari 5

[image: IOS Safari 5]

.

.

.

**Following browsers now supports color widget**

Firefox Desktop 29

[image: Firefox 29 color input Ubuntu]

Opera Desktop 11

[image: Opera desktop color input]

Chrome Desktop 20:

[image: chrome input type color Ubuntu]

Android 4.4 / Chrome Mobile :

[image: chrome mobile color input]

Opera mobile:

[image: opera mobile color input]

Blackberry:

[image: blackberry color input]

Firefox os 1.3

Firefox os now supports color input but i still don't have a screen shot

If u want u can use this http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

Comment: wow, thanks for going to the trouble of posting all these screen shots on different devices :)

Comment: and if you're app requires IE?  Any simple libs to include?

Comment: you cpuld fallback to jquery ui

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with input type=range. Everything was working on all browser, except for Internet Explorer 10. It was not a problem with Internet Explorer, given that I could see the slider in other websites. The solution was to turn off i.e. compatibility view for my website.

Answer (score 0):

the best solution I think is to use jquery plugins.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="slider"></div>


    </body>

</html>
```

http://jqueryui.com/slider/