# Why does the following line of PHP not work?

Tags: php, html, input, colors

`echo "<input type\"color\" name=\"backColorSect\" value=\"" . $backColorSect . "\">";`
My browser supports `input type="color"`, but that particular line only displays an `input type="text"`. Of course, it is located between `<?php` and `?>`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed an `=` after `type` in

```
echo "<input type\"color\" name=\"backColorSect\" value=\"" . $backColorSect . "\">";
```

Please replace it as

```
echo "<input type=\"color\" name=\"backColorSect\" value=\"" . $backColorSect . "\">";
```

Also, If you are testing it in firefox, see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12456164/3168859)

It says

Since HTML5 hasn't been completely standardized yet, not all browsers do support these input types. The *intended* behaviour is to fall back to `<input type="text">`.

↪ [See here for more information on browser support for HTML5 input types.](http://caniuse.com/#search=input%20type)

You can [test for support](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#input-types) using the Modernizr library or with some custom JavaScript. If you detect a certain HTML5 feature isn't available, you can fall back to [JavaScript](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)-[based](http://www.queness.com/post/10081/11-javascript-color-pickers-plugins) [alternatives](https://startpage.com/do/search?q=javascript%20slider%20input).

Answer (score 1):

You could also replace the whole escaping thing, with the usage of single quotes:

```
echo "<input type='color' name='backColorSect' value='{$backColorSect}'>";
```