# Embedding HTML5 support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, google-chrome, firefox

I have a rails app which uses some HTML5 features, mainly for input fields, such as

```
<input id="operation_date_from_date" name="operation_date[from_date]" type="date" />
```

I am familiar with the lack of proper support in browsers that aren't Chrome, and I know that there's some kind of solution, as suggested here: [HTML5 input type date, color, range support in Firefox and Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455506/html5-input-type-date-color-range-support-in-firefox-and-internet-explorer)

So, two questions:

A. Is there some kind of a config file where I can put the webshims solution which will apply for the whole app?

B. As the app is often being used on computers without internet connection (for security reasons), can I trust this solution to work offline as well?

Thanks a lot,
Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A.** You could use [`webshims-rails`](https://github.com/whatcould/webshims-rails) gem that allows you to integrate the [Webshim](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html) library. Just follow the installation steps to add it to your stack.

**B.** Yes, as long as you can access the app from your browser, of course!