# Regular expression for "+" not working in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, reactjs

I want to validate simply numbers in reactjs form by proceeding the number with + symbol.

For example when I type "+9829" and enter submit then the validation should work.

This is my regular expression validation code:

```
if(!(/(\+)?\d+/g.test(checkValidPhone)))
```

`(\+)?\d+/g` This RegExp works fine in Chrome and IE but not in Mozilla because in Mozilla the + symbol is not getting validated.

See [this Plunkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/b435LzuuL3S7W76zZy2a?p=preview).

Anyone with any suggestion?

Comment: Did you tried `\\+` ?

Comment: And remove `g` at the end since you are using `RegExp#test`

Comment: @Rahul i just tried that, still no result

Comment: Did you try it without the capture group? `/\+?d+/.test(input)` ought to work for a test.

Answer (score 0):

Try and test following code in Firefox because it's working fine for me.

Take a note that to validate string as digits followed by `+` you have to use anchors `^` and `$` otherwise `.test()` will be true for other non-valid cases such as `+900n`.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById('num').value;

    //look for "+" followed by digits
    var patt = /^(\+)?\d+$/;
    var result = patt.test(str);

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Do a number followed by + :</p>
<input type="text" id="num">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/b435LzuuL3S7W76zZy2a?p=preview

Please check the above link in Mozilla. In your example i see you are using the input type as text but i want number. For text it is working fine for me as well.

Comment: @Boris: Then I guess it has to do with browser version. Which one are you using ?

Comment: [This answer might help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269004/html5-input-type-number-in-firefox)

Comment: [*The value sanitization algorithm is as follows: If the value of the element is not a valid floating-point number, then set it to the empty string instead.*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-(type=number)) @Boris